# thunderbird local archive folder missing

Tags: directory, local, archive, thunderbird

In Thunderbird, I've setup in my account parameter / Copy and Folder, the archive to be stored in a local folder, with yearly subfolder and conservation of original tree structure.

In my folder list under local folder I've got all my yearly folder except one : 2022.

In my %AppData%\Thunderbird\Profiles\axb93fh9.{profile_name}\Mail\Local Folders\Archives.sbd
I've got all "20XX", "20XX.msf" and "20XX.sbd" file except 2022.sbd.

I haven't delete it and don't know how to regereate it.
the 2022 and 2022.msf file are filled (2.3gO and 6 Mo respectively).
and so don't get the tree for 2022.

How can I restore my 2022 archive folder, without loosing my mails?

TH v115.9.0 64 bits
Windows 10 v22H2